# por que mis condiciones de parada en la función regla falsa no funcionan?

Tags: python

```
from math import*
from pylab import*

def biseccion(funcion_evaluada,lim1,lim2,errort):
    if funcion_evaluada(lim1)* funcion_evaluada(lim2) <0:
        raiz=lim1
        cont=0
        while abs(funcion_evaluada(raiz))>errort:
            raiz=(lim1+lim2)/2
            if funcion_evaluada(lim1)*funcion_evaluada(raiz)<0:
                lim2=raiz
            else:
                lim1=raiz
            cont=cont+1
            print (cont," ",raiz)
        return raiz

    else:
        return 'no es menor que 0 no toca el eje x no hay raiz !'


def regla_falsa(funcion_evaluada,lim1,lim2,errort):
    if funcion_evaluada(lim1)* funcion_evaluada(lim2) <0:
        cont=0
        while abs((lim2 - lim1) / lim2) > errort or cont<=100:
            raiz = lim2 - (funcion_evaluada(lim2) * (lim2-lim1)) / (funcion_evaluada(lim2) - funcion_evaluada(lim1))
            if funcion_evaluada(lim1) * funcion_evaluada(raiz) < 0:
                lim2 = raiz
            else:
                lim1 = raiz
            cont=cont+1
            print(cont," ",raiz)
        return raiz
    else:
        return 'no es menor que 0 no toca el eje x no hay raiz !'







def funcion_evaluada(x):
    return eval(funcion)



funcion = input('ingrese funcion: ')
lim1= float(input('limite 1 del intervalo: '))
lim2 = float(input('limite 2 del intervalo: '))
errort = float(input('ingrese error de tolerancia: '))



raiz_biseccion = biseccion (funcion_evaluada,lim1,lim2,errort)
print ('la raiz por el metodo de biseccion es: ', raiz_biseccion)
raiz_regla_falsa = regla_falsa (funcion_evaluada,lim1,lim2,errort)
print ('la  raiz por el metodo de regla falsa es: ', raiz_regla_falsa)
```

la funcion regla falsa nunca sale del while y quiero que cuando se cumpla una condicion o la otra pare y no para.

se supone que coloco el contador, para que cuando lo haga 100 veces salga del while y no sale

Comment: Hola Juan, bienvenido. deberias [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/52637/edit) la pregunta para dejar solo la funcion involucrada ya que el resto de el codigo no es relevante. Un saludo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> while abs((lim2 - lim1) / lim2) > errort or cont<=100:
> ```

[El operador logico `OR`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disyunci%C3%B3n_l%C3%B3gica) devuelve `True` si **al menos una** de las condiciones es `True`.

Para tu caso, necesitas cambiar el `OR` por un `AND`.

No solo para que te haga un maximo de 100 iteraciones sino porque si ha hecho menos de 100 estará entrando en el `while` sin que se cumpla la primera condicion (que es la importante no?).

Con un [operador logico `AND`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunci%C3%B3n_l%C3%B3gica) te aseguras que ambas condiciones se cumplen ya que solo devuelve `True` si **todas las comprobaciones** son `True`.